# How do I upload a new Mysql database of tables?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've been assigned a downloaded xyz.sql file (which recreates
tables and data that resided on another server.

I have running MAMP 1.8.4 on my Mac 10.6.2.

I finally got my mysql prompt at the command line using:
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql mysql –uroot –proot

Now, what command can take that file for input, give my Mysql 
server a new database name to use (xyz), and upload the 
whole thing?

What I mean is - I have other databases that my phpMyadmin 
sees.  I want it to now see this new xyz database the next
time I open phpMyadmin.

Answer (score 3):

To execute the file, at the mysql prompt: `source <filename>`

If you need to switch to database xyz first, the command is: `use xyz`

Answer (score 1):

change into the directory where the sql file is stored, then you'll need to execute something like

```
mysql –uroot –proot < xyz.sql
```